# MySQL: how to select record with latest date before a certain date

Tags: mysql, date, select

Assume a simple table as follows containing status events for two users. A status_id of 1 makes them 'active', anything else makes them de-active.
I need to find out all those users that **became** inactive within one year of, for example, 2015-05-01 (not including that date).

```
CREATE TABLE user_status(
      user_id INT,
      status_id INT,
      date_assigned VARCHAR(10) );

 INSERT INTO user_status( user_id, status_id, date_assigned)
 VALUES
 (1234, 1, '2015-01-01'), -- 1234 becomes active (status id = 1)
 (1234, 2, '2015-07-01'), -- 1234 de-activated for reason 2

 (5678, 1, '2015-02-01'), -- 5678 becomes active (status id = 1)
 (5678, 3, '2015-04-01'), -- 5678 de-activated for reason 3
 (5678, 5, '2015-06-01'); -- 5678 de-activated for reason 5
```

Using the query

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM user_status t1
WHERE t1.date_assigned = (SELECT MIN(t2.date_assigned)       -- the first occurrence
                          FROM  user_status t2
                          WHERE t2.user_id =  t1.user_id     -- for this user
                          AND t2.status_id <> 1              -- where status not active
                          AND t2.date_assigned BETWEEN       -- within 1 yr of given date
                               '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY -- (not including that date)
                          AND 
                               '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
                          )
```

I can get the result

```
user_id   status_id   date_assigned
 1234       2          2015-07-01
 5678       5          2015-06-01
```

This is sort of right but user 5678 should not be there because although they had an inactive event within the date range, they were already inactive before the desired date range began and so did not **become** inactive within that range.

I need to add a bit to my query along the lines of 'only show me those users who had an inactive event **and** where the previous status_id for that user was 1, ie they were active at the time the inactive event happened.

Can anyone help me to get the syntax correct?
See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/801c9/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  `NOT EXISTS` to your query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM user_status t1
WHERE t1.date_assigned = (SELECT MIN(t2.date_assigned)       -- the first occurance
                          FROM  user_status t2
                          WHERE t2.user_id =  t1.user_id     -- for this user
                          AND t2.status_id <> 1              -- where status not active
                          AND t2.date_assigned BETWEEN       -- within 1 yr of given date
                               '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY -- (not including that date)
                          AND 
                               '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
                          )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1                         -- such a record should not exist
                      FROM user_status t3
                      WHERE t3.user_id =  t1.user_id   -- for this user
                             AND t3.status_id <> 1     -- where status is not active
                             AND t3.date_assigned <    -- before the examined period
                               '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/801c9/4)

**Edit:**

You can use the following query that also considers the case of having multiple activation dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_status
WHERE (user_id, date_assigned) IN (
  -- get last de-activation date   
  SELECT t1.user_id, MAX(t1.date_assigned)
  FROM user_status AS t1
  JOIN (
    -- get last activation date 
    SELECT user_id, MAX(date_assigned) AS activation_date
    FROM user_status 
    WHERE status_id = 1
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.date_assigned > t2.activation_date
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING MAX(date_assigned) BETWEEN '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND
         MIN(date_assigned) > '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work. if you add another record (5678, 1, '2015-04-20'), so that 5678 becomes active again just before the date range (after previously being de-active)  then they don't get picked up as deactivating for a second time on 2015-06-01

Comment: Ah, That seems to work correctly, thank you. I have accepted your answer with the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Self join solution : finding minimum ( the first time the status changed) within your date criteria:

```
select a.user_id,b.status_id,max(b.date_assigned) 
from user_status a
inner join user_status b 
on a.user_id=b.user_id 
and a.date_assigned <b.date_assigned 
where b.status_id >1 and a.status_id=1 
group by a.user_id,b.status_id 
having max(b.date_assigned)> '2015-05-01'
and max(b.date_assigned) <='2016-05-01'
```

Comment: Same problem as the answer from Giorogos I'm afraid. If another record is added so that user 5678 becomes active again on 2015-04-20 (just before the date range starts), then they should get picked up as deactivating for the second time on 2015-06-01 but this code doesn't show that record. Incidentally I use INTERVAL as the start date for the period is passed as a parameter in the real system, although that doesn't affect your solution.

Comment: Still only gives me record for user 1234, not for 5678 as well using.
CREATE TABLE user_status(
      user_id INT,
      status_id INT,
      date_assigned VARCHAR(10) );
 INSERT INTO user_status( user_id, status_id, date_assigned)
 VALUES
 (1234, 1, '2015-01-01'), -- 1234 becomes active (status id = 1)
 (1234, 2, '2015-07-01'), -- 1234 de-active for reason 2
 
 (5678, 1, '2015-02-01'), -- 5678 becomes active (status id = 1)
 (5678, 3, '2015-04-01'), -- 5678 de-active for reason 3
 (5678, 1, '2015-04-20'), -- 5678 active again
 (5678, 5, '2015-06-01'); -- 5678 de-active for reason 5

Comment: Have you changed anything from my code? because it works just fine on my environment

Comment: edit your question with the desired result from this new dummy dataset please

Comment: The 'incorrect' result shown in my question with three records for user 5678 ( ie showing user 5678 as having de-activated) turns into a correct result if a fourth record is added that reactivates user 5678 on 2015-04-20, just before the date range .